# Joda Time PeriodFormatterBuilder

Tags: java, jodatime

I just tested the PeriodFormatterBuilder in Joda Time framework. When I am appending the weeks output to the builder, the calculated time is correct. But if weeks are not appended, what is actually what I want, the builder is just dropping 7 days:

```
public class JodaTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // builder 1 (weeks inc.)
    PeriodFormatterBuilder b1 = new PeriodFormatterBuilder();
    b1.appendYears().appendSuffix(" year", " years");
    b1.appendSeparator(" ");
    b1.appendMonths().appendSuffix(" month", " months");
    b1.appendSeparator(" ");
    // appends weeks ...
    b1.appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" week", " weeks");
    b1.appendSeparator(" ");
    b1.appendDays().appendSuffix(" day", " days");
    b1.appendSeparator(" ");
    b1.printZeroIfSupported().minimumPrintedDigits(2);
    b1.appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour", " hours");
    b1.appendSeparator(" ");
    b1.appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minutes");
    b1.appendSeparator(" ");
    b1.appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" seconds");
    PeriodFormatter f1 = b1.toFormatter();

    // builder 2 (weeks not inc.)
    PeriodFormatterBuilder b2 = new PeriodFormatterBuilder();
    b2.appendYears().appendSuffix(" year", " years");
    b2.appendSeparator(" ");
    b2.appendMonths().appendSuffix(" month", " months");
    b2.appendSeparator(" ");
    // does not append weeks ...
    b2.appendDays().appendSuffix(" day", " days");
    b2.appendSeparator(" ");
    b2.printZeroIfSupported().minimumPrintedDigits(2);
    b2.appendHours().appendSuffix(" hour", " hours");
    b2.appendSeparator(" ");
    b2.appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minutes");
    b2.appendSeparator(" ");
    b2.appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" seconds");
    PeriodFormatter f2 = b2.toFormatter();

    Period period = new Period(new Date().getTime(), new DateTime(2014, 12, 25, 0, 0).getMillis());

    System.out.println(f1.print(period));
    System.out.println(f2.print(period)); // 7 days missing?
   }
}
```

Prints out:

```
 1 month 1 week 2 days 09 hours 56 minutes 21 seconds 
 1 month 2 days 09 hours 56 minutes 21 seconds
```

In the second line the day value should be "9 days". How to make the builder summarize the correct day values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard `Period` object divides the period into years, months, weeks, days, and the time fields. A duration of more than a week will add to the `weeks` field, and the `days` field is, more or less, the remainder of dividing the duration by 7.

The `PeriodFormatter` merely prints the fields as they are inside the `Period` object. It doesn't make any calculations. If the days field is `2`, it will stay `2` even if you haven't included the weeks.

To get the period with weeks represented in the days field instead of the weeks field, you should either create a period with a different type:

```
Period periodWithoutWeeks = new Period(
     Date().getTime(),
     new DateTime(2014, 12, 25, 0, 0).getMillis(),
     PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
```

Or convert your period to the type without weeks by assuming a week is a standard 7 days:

```
Period periodWithoutWeeks =  period.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
```

Now you can print it with either of the formatters:

```
System.out.println( f2.print(periodWithoutWeeks) );
```

Comment: While promising, this throws exception to me: IllegalArgumentException: Period does not support field 'weeks'.